# Can I publish an application that some of its features and UI are altered due to expiration date?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, trial

I'm working on a Keyboard extension for iOS. One of the requirements I have is to provide a functionality in which the keyboard's design and word prediction capabilities are **temporary**. Meaning after a month/45 days I want to change the keyboard looks and disable the word prediction capabilities until the user buys those again using the in-app purchase mechanism.

Basically I want to provide the app for the user for a **trial period** after which the application becomes less functional.

I have implemented those behaviors in the Android app and now I'm required to perform the same functionality in the iOS app.

**The question is:** Is this type of app behavior is allowed by Apple, or will I be rejected for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer is No, You can't Publish trial Base Apps.

As per App Store Review Guidelines :

**2.9 Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected. Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must follow the TestFlight guidelines**

**Possible Solution:**
I Don't know what features you have in your App. But this might help you.

- You can use Subscription based inApp purchases where user can purchase & enable some feature & that will be available for some limited period.
- For more details check out here: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Hope it will help you.